# extracting string within python list

Tags: python

How do I split this:

`str = "['A20150710', 1.0]"` to get `'A20150710'`?

I tried the below line but not sure how to proceed from there:

```
str.split(',')
```

Comment: Let's take a step back, how did you get this: `str = "['A20150710', 1.0]"`? That looks like a string representation of a list. Indeed, your title implies that, but note, **there are no lists here**

Answer (score 3):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert string representation to a list and get the first item:

```
import ast

str = "['A20150710', 1.0]"

print(ast.literal_eval(str)[0])
# A20150710
```

Comment: this is almost certainly a duplicate if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Split on `,` and remove punctuations

```
import string
str1 = "['A20150710', 1.0]"
str1=str1.split(',')[0]
str1.translate(None,string.punctuation) #'A20150710'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use eval to parse the string, then fetch the information you want

```
str = "['A20150710', 1.0]"
eval(str)[0] # A20150710
```

**!!!Be careful!!! Using `eval` is a security risk, as it executes arbitrary Python expressions**